# ADO Windows With SP1 and VB6

Tags: windows-7, vb6, ado, mdac

I've been reading about the GUIDs changing for ADO/MDAC in Windows 7 service pack1 for VB6 apps. I need to recopile my compontents and replace the deprecated ones with the new one. My question is if my VB6 app is only going to be installed on windows 7 with service pack 1 or windows 2008 with the latest service pack will my VB6 app still work or do I still need to install something else too?

Comment: It failed on a Server 2008 machine here until I recompiled against the compatability typelib.

Comment: On Win7 SP1 we are using ADO typelib from Win7 RTM to compile everything-compatible executables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946883/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-on-new-adodb-connection-only-if-com/8952634#8952634

Answer (score 0):

The updates you need to fix this problem [are here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640696).

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx) explains a bit more about what happened and how they **DRASTICALLY** (Microsoft's emphasis) underestimated the number of developers that would be re-compiling ADO applications on Win7 SP1.